# Conditional formatting: highlighting rows based on condition

Tags: excel, highlight

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Date       Value
5/27/2017  5
6/10/2017  7
6/24/2017  8
7/8/2017   5
7/22/2017  10
```

I want to highlight the most recent row, meaning the row with the date closest to today. I know I need to use Excel's conditional formatting capability, so I created the indicator column `_inRange`, which derives from this function:

```
=IF(AND(A2 <= TODAY()), TODAY() < A3), 1, 0)
```

The new table:

Date       Value    _inRange
5/27/2017  5        0
6/10/2017  7        0
6/24/2017  8        1
7/8/2017   5        0
7/22/2017  10       0

So, where `_inRange` equals 1, the row should be highlighted. I can highlight the `_inRange` cell properly, but am having difficulties highlighting the entire row. Can anyone provide direction here? I looked at [this Exceljet post](https://exceljet.net/formula/highlight-entire-rows) but obviously was left with questions.

Edit:

I changed `_inRange` to boolean (I don't think boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` versus 1-0 is the main issue, though) and am still having issues:

```
Date    Value   _inRange
5/27/2017   5   FALSE
6/10/2017   7   FALSE
6/24/2017   8   TRUE
7/8/2017    5   FALSE
7/22/2017   10  FALSE
```

Here's a picture of my conditional formatting window:

[image]

I first select the entire table, then go to `Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Equal To` and set the value as `TRUE`. Then I change the column as E. Trauger suggested but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

In the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager (Home->Conditional Formatting->Manage Rules...) make sure your conditional format is correct in the "Rule" Column and then make sure the "Applies to" column is also correct.  I suspect this is your problem.

Try changing the rule to: `=$C2=1`
And change range of application to: `=$A$2:$C$10` (or whatever the C column goes to)

Comment: Your rule should be `=$C2=TRUE` and your "Applies to" column should be  `=$A$2:$C$6`

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be to use the conditional formatting on the entire row, where for any cell in that row, it is going to check the _inRange of that row. Something like this, after New Formatting Rule --> Use a Formula to Determine which cells to format:

```
=INDEX(C:C,ROW())=1
```

Replace C:C with whatever column _inRange is in, and apply the formatting to the entire table.

Comment: E. Trauger's answer seems to be a much simpler and better answer for this.